# Spring Batch - Delay between Tasklet execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm currently looking into Spring Batch to create persistable tasks. My tasks are, most of the time, quite simple, e.g.:

1. Submit something to an API
2. Wait until the task is finished (by repeatedly calling an API to check the status)
3. Retrieve the results

This looks like something I could achieve using a [Tasklet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#taskletStep).

```java
public class WaitingForAPITask implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)  {
        if(checkExternalAPIIfReady()){
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
        

        return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
    }

}
```

However, using this implementation would bombard the API with hundreds or thousands of calls per second. Hence my question, is there any way to control the delay between successive `execute(...)` calls? An easy solution would be to include a Thread.sleep() call in the `execute(...)` method. However this feels kind of like a bad coding style. Are there any other possibilities? Or is there a better solution I'm missing? I'm currently looking at Spring Batch due to the fact that jobs are persisted and the possibility to chain tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is polling, and Spring Batch provides the [Poller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/poller/Poller.html) API for that:

```
Poller<Result> poller = new DirectPoller(3000); 3s polling interval

 final long id = remoteService.execute(); // do something remotely

 Future<Result> future = poller.poll(new Callable<Result> {
     public Object call() {
           // Look for the result (null if not ready)
           return remoteService.get(id);
     }
 });

 Result result = future.get(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The `DirectPoller` implementation provides a parameter to specify the polling interval which should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! The Poller looks exactly what I was looking for. Would you recommend using it in the execute() method of a Tasklet? If this works, I could separate my Job cleanly into three steps, i.e. submission -> polling your recommended Poller API -> result retrieval. Thanks!

Comment: You can use it in the `execute` method. But if you are going to pull the polling logic outside the step, you can do the polling in a step listener after the submission step.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine experiencing the same issue, If add poller in the tasklet execute method still spring batch every time calls the execute method internally. am I missing anything here?

Comment: TaskRequest taskRequest = new TaskRequest(executionContext.getString("task_id"));
      Poller<Task> poller = new DirectPoller(100);
      Future<Task> future = poller.poll(() -> constructor.task(taskRequest));
      Task result = future.get(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if (result.getStatus().equals("DONE") || result.getStatus().equals("FAILED") || result.getStatus().equals("CANCELED")) {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
      } else {
        return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
      }